# cocos2d particle performance

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using particles for an iphone application using cocos2d. The framerate drops as the particles are shown. What is the best way to clean these up as not to affect performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using too many particles that was taking up too much memory. I changed the way I did things.

Comment: Lower the number of particles you are spawning until it still looks right and creates the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tutorial on how to pool and reuse particles. I found that even though I was removing my emitters with cleanup they were still sitting in memory. After pooling the number of active particle systems dropped from 700 after 2 minutes to 34. The tutorial can be found [here](http://www.deluge.co/?q=reuse-particle-emitter-cocos2d).